# How to keep a floating Infragistics contentpane wpf window "visible" all time?

Tags: wpf, infragistics, floating

Please need help. Have been struggling with this for last 24 hours.

I have a small floating Infragistics contentpane - width:100, height:100 which I'm placing over at coordinate x:10, y:10. There is a third party application window (x:0, y:0, width:640, height:640).

How do I make my floating contentpane to stay visible all the time even if I were to click on the third party application ?

Also, I would like to remove the close button on this floating contentpane. I tried playing around with PaneHeaderPresenter style in the DockManagerGeneric.xaml, but no luck. The changes in the style seem to have an impact on the contentpanes docked, but not on floating contentpanes. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the AllowClose to false in the Content Pane Property, the Close button would still be visible though.

Comment: The ContenPane also has the property CloseButtonVisibility="Hidden" that allows you to hide the button, at least on the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

For keeping the window on top of other applications, you can set the Topmost property of the Window to true in the ToolWindowLoaded event:

```
void xamDockManager1_ToolWindowLoaded(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DockManager.Events.PaneToolWindowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Window.AllowClose = false;
    Window w = Window.GetWindow(e.Window);
    w.Topmost = true;
}
```

For hiding the closing button, look at [this post](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/58008/295785.aspx#295785) on the Infragistics forums.